# How to get checkbox state from an element that is pass as a function parameter jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I just started to learn jquery. and my problem is like this:

I have a html:

```
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id01" value="Sensor1">
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id02" value="Sensor2">
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id03" value="Sensor3">
```

and I create a function that calls another function and pass $(this) as a parameter:

```
if( $(this).is('.feature')) {
    add_feature($(this));
}
```

All I want is to get the checkbox state and other element attributes value such as id value, name, data-attribute value. Here's what I have tried:

```
function add_feature(element){
   console.log($(element).attr('id'));
   console.log($(element).prop('checked'));
}
```

But it says undefined. is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: Can you make this runnable ?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(element);` if you add it inside your `add_feature` function?

Comment: The console.log(element) output is the element of a selected checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a collection, use method `each()`.

> The `each()` method specifies a function to run for each matched element.

```js
$(".feature").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    console.log($(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id01" value="Sensor1" checked>
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id02" value="Sensor2">
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id03" value="Sensor3">
```

The second solution is using a function call from `add_feature()`.

```js
function add_feature(element) {
    console.log($(element).attr("id"));
    console.log($(element).prop("checked"));
}

$(".feature").each(function () {
    add_feature($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id01" value="Sensor1" checked>
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id02" value="Sensor2">
<input class="feature" type="checkbox" id="id03" value="Sensor3">
```